# java.lang.AssertionError: found value shows as null

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse, testng.xml

I wanted check whether the text field value is same or not to the expected value which i mentioned on the code

This is the ***text field*** which i needed the value

input type="text" value="sadas" class="mdl-textfield__input" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Enter last name"

***Error*** what i got,

TestNG error message shows as follows,
**java.lang.AssertionError: expected [6234] but found []**
and nothing printed for the console as well

I have tried with "Assert.assertTrue(lastName.equals("lastName : 6234"));" too

```
@Test
    public void tc001() {       
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='email']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='email']")).clear(); driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='email']")).sendKeys("x@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).clear();driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).sendKeys("123456");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and  normalize-space(.)='Forgot Your Password?']) [1]/preceding::button[1]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Nadee")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Profile")).click();
    String lastName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='last_name']")).getText();
    Assert.assertEquals(lastName ,"6234");
    System.out.println(lastName);   
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log Out")).click();
    }
```

How can i fix this? And why i'm getting this error when expected value same to the found?(when manually checking the system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add wait before getting value of lastname field. You are clicking a link before getting last name value, there is a possibility that page was not fully loaded.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Profile")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@name='last_name']")));
String lastName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='last_name']")).getAttribute("value");
system.out.println("Last Name value is: "+ lastName); // check the output on console too
Assert.assertEquals(lastName ,"6234");
```

Comment: Earler,I have tried my code as same to you,but it also return same result.
I have tried your one too,It also showing as null value

Comment: WebDriverWait textfeild  = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
textfeild.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='last_name']")));
String lastName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='last_name']")).getText();    
Assert.assertEquals(lastName ,"6234");
System.out.println(lastName);

Comment: try this 
String lastName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='last_name']")).getAttribute("value");